# How to simplify Option processing

Tags: scala, fold

I have a source List with data and I want to sort it to 3 lists with cleaned data, with updated data and logged. All elements from source have to be in logged list. All elements with non empty value have to be in cleaned list and if flag is updated the element also have to appear in updated folder.

According the example:

- updated = 2,4 el
- logged = 1,2,3,4 el
- cleaned = 3, 4 el

Could you help me simplify written code:

```
case class Source(value: Option[String], date: String, isUpdate: Boolean)

case class Cleaned(value: String, date: String)
case class Logged(value: String, date: String)
case class Updated(value: String, date: String)

val sources: List[Source] = List(
    Source(Option.empty[String], "2020-01-09", false), // 1
    Source(Option.empty[String], "2020-01-09", true), // 2
    Source(Option("Some Data"), "2020-01-09", false), // 3
    Source(Option("Some Data 2"), "2020-01-09", true) // 4
)


val target = sources.foldLeft(List.empty[Updated], List.empty[Logged], List.empty[Cleaned]){
    case ((updated, logged, cleaned), el) if el.isUpdate =>
        (updated  :+ Updated(el.value.getOrElse(""), el.date),
            logged :+ Logged(el.value.getOrElse(""), el.date),
            el.value.fold(cleaned)(d => cleaned :+ Cleaned(d, el.date))
        )

    case ((updated, logged, cleaned), el) =>
        (updated,
            logged :+ Logged(el.value.getOrElse(""), el.date),
            el.value.fold(cleaned)(d => cleaned :+ Cleaned(d, el.date))
        )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `updated` should contain the second element? The way I read the requirement is that the value should exist and the flag to be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct your own folding operator and pass that through using a foldRight method:

```
type Targets = (List[Updated], List[Logged], List[Cleaned])
val target = sources.foldRight(List.empty[Updated], List.empty[Logged], List.empty[Cleaned])(process)

def process(el: Source, acc: Targets): Targets = acc match {
  case (updated, logged, cleaned) => el match {
    case Source(None, date, false) =>
      (updated, Logged("", date) :: logged, cleaned)

    case Source(Some(value), date, false) =>
      (updated, Logged(value, date) :: logged, Cleaned(value, date) :: cleaned)

    case Source(None, date, true) =>
      (Updated("", date) :: updated, Logged("", date) :: logged, cleaned)

    case Source(Some(value), date, true) =>
      (Updated(value, date) :: updated, Logged(value, date) :: logged, Cleaned(value, date) :: cleaned)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe this is the kind of problems that are best solved using recursion.
The code is larger, but IMHO, easier to understand and to change.

```
type Result = (List[Logged], List[Cleaned], List[Updated])

def process(data: List[Source]): Result = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Source], logged: List[Logged], cleaned: List[Cleaned], updated: List[Updated]): Result =
    remaining match {
      case Source(Some(value), date, true) :: xs =>
        loop(
          remaining = xs,
          Logged(value = value, date) :: logged,
          Cleaned(value, date) :: cleaned,
          Updated(value, date) :: updated
        )
      
      case Source(Some(value), date, false) :: xs =>
        loop(
          remaining = xs,
          Logged(value = value, date) :: logged,
          Cleaned(value, date) :: cleaned,
          updated
        )
      
      case Source(None, date, _) :: xs =>
        loop(
          remaining = xs,
          Logged(value = "", date) :: logged,
          cleaned,
          updated
        )
      
      case Nil=>
        // If the order is not important, remove all the reverse.
        (
          logged.reverse,
          cleaned.reverse,
          updated.reverse
        )
    }
  
  loop(remaining = data, logged = List.empty, cleaned = List.empty, updated = List.empty)
}
```

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/I3sQc3yrTfubrOevIEHZKQ/1).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are massive performance issues, just process the list three times:

```
val target =
  (
    sources.flatMap { el =>
      if (el.isUpdate) Some(Updated(el.value.getOrElse(""), el.date)) else None
    },
    sources.map(el => Logged(el.value.getOrElse(""), el.date)),
    sources.flatMap { el =>
      el.value.map(d => Cleaned(d, el.date))
    }
  )
```